# Error: Character ' ', hexadecimal value 0xb is illegal in XML documents

Tags: c#, xml

After calling a REST API, I get a response in XML but it contains a character that's causing issues when deserializing it to an object. I copied the XML document as a test data but when I copy the content in Visual Studio 2012 the error message shows up.

Does anyone know how I could get around this error?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033692/problem-with-hexadecimal-values-in-xml-document) will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character 0x0b is [not a legal character in XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#charsets).

If the XML is generated using an XML library, such characters will normally be escaped properly (e.g. "&#0B;").

This suggests that the author of the REST service you're calling has committed the sin of generating XML manually instead of using a library.

The best solution is to get the author of the REST service to confess his sin, correct it and promise not to offend again.

> In the meantime, are there anything practical that I could do in this position?

Of course you could "fix" the data before processing it (e.g. replace the character 0x0b by the correct escape sequence "&#0B;").  But you would still be open to other errors caused by malformed XML sent by the Web Service.

Comment: In the meantime, are there anything practical that I could do in this position? The application I'm working on requires data from this REST API in order to drive the business logic.